# Checking duplicate objects in array with some and 2 conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have data from a form that needs to be compared to its older data.
I want to check if an object was in the previous old data and if its slot number changed.

**Data example**

```js
const oldData = [{name: "John", slot: 2}, {name: "John", slot: 3}, {name: "John", slot: 4}]
const newData = [{name: "Alex", slot: 2}, {name: "John", slot: 3}, {name: "Bob", slot: 4}, {name: "John", slot: 5}]

  // Duplications
  const duplicateCreate = newData.filter((order1) => {
    return oldData.some((order2) => {
      return (
        order1.name === order2.name &&
        order1.slot !== order2.slot
      );
    });
  });

  console.log(duplicateCreate)
```

**What I expect the output to be**

```js
[{name: "John", slot: 5}]
```

**What I get**

```js
[{name: "John", slot: 3}, {name: "John", slot: 5}]
```

I have no Idea why the some function is passing john slot 2 as truthy, if I change my code to
order1.slot === order2.slot then the output will be

```js
[{name: "John", slot: 3}]
```

So clearly its reading the && condition and clearly that logic works but the logic of checking for the object whose name is john and slot !== the same isnt working the way its written from my understanding so I am kind of at a loss right now.

Comment: It's returning true for `{name: "John", slot: 2}` because the condition is true with that and `{name: "John", slot: 4}`

Comment: When I run this code, I get `[{name: "John", slot: 3}, {name: "John", slot: 5}] ` (slot 3 instead of 2).

Comment: yeah I meant slot 3 idk how to edit

Comment: @001 how is "John" === "John" && 3 !== 3 true?

Comment: It's not, but John/3 is matching John/5 and you are using `Array.some`, so as long as one returns true, it'll pass the filter.

Comment: So would that mean that .some is matching only the first condition of John and not both name and slot because that would seem unintuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran a couple of scenarios and this works fine:

```
const oldData = [{name: "John", slot: 2}, {name: "John", slot: 3}, {name: "John", slot: 4}];
const newData = [{name: "Alex", slot: 2}, {name: "John", slot: 3}, {name: "Bob", slot: 4}, {name: "John", slot: 5}];

const duplicateCreate = newData.filter((order1) => {
  const exactMatch = oldData.some(order2 => order1.name === order2.name && order1.slot === order2.slot);
  const nameMatch = oldData.some(order2 => order1.name === order2.name);

  return nameMatch && !exactMatch;
});

console.log(duplicateCreate);  // [{name: "John", slot: 5}]
```

**Edit**: Explanation

**Original Code**:
For each item in `newData`, it checks if there's an item in `oldData` with the same name but a different slot. This approach leads to false positives, like including `{name: "John", slot: 3}`, since there's another `"John"` in `oldData` with a different slot.

**Revised Code**:
For each item in newData, it checks two things:

- If there's an exact match in `oldData (both name and slot).
- If there's a name match in `oldData` (just the name). The item from `newData` is included in the result only if there's a name match but not an exact match. This ensures that only true duplicates (same name, different slot, and no exact match in `oldData`) are included in the result.

Comment: It looks like this works and it makes sense, I dont get why the original code doesnt when it works for an exact match. Im going to try this in my code. Thank you

Comment: @JayyRon Just added an explanation on why your code didnt work and what i did to make it work

Comment: So I can see why it produced false positives since like you said the old data had johns with different slots...but then now my question is why did it return john with the same slots and not the others with different slots like john/2 and john/4?

Answer (score 0):

Same as **jagmitg**, failed to convert to single check. But, it will be a bit more optimal in speed due to exiting the calculation on first .some:

```
  const duplicateCreate = newData.filter((order1) => {
    return oldData.some((order2) => {
      return (
        order1.name === order2.name 
      ) 
    }) && !oldData.some((order2) => {
        return (
        order1.name === order2.name && order1.slot === order2.slot)
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to check all conditions in jagmitg's solution:

```js
const oldData = [{name: "John", slot: 2}, {name: "John", slot: 3}, {name: "John", slot: 4}];
const newData = [{name: "Alex", slot: 2}, {name: "John", slot: 3}, {name: "Bob", slot: 4}, {name: "John", slot: 5}];

const duplicateCreate = newData.filter((order1) => {
  const nameMatch = oldData.some(order2 => order1.name === order2.name);
  if(!nameMatch) return;
  return !oldData.some(order2 => order1.name === order2.name && order1.slot === order2.slot);
});

console.log(duplicateCreate);
```

And a benchmark:

[image]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="10000000">

    const oldData = [{name: "John", slot: 2}, {name: "John", slot: 3}, {name: "John", slot: 4}];
    const newData = [{name: "Alex", slot: 2}, {name: "John", slot: 3}, {name: "Bob", slot: 4}, {name: "John", slot: 5}];

// @benchmark jagmitg

newData.filter((order1) => {
  const exactMatch = oldData.some(order2 => order1.name === order2.name && order1.slot === order2.slot);
  const nameMatch = oldData.some(order2 => order1.name === order2.name);
  return nameMatch && !exactMatch;
});


// @benchmark Alexander

newData.filter((order1) => {
  const nameMatch = oldData.some(order2 => order1.name === order2.name);
  if(!nameMatch) return;
  return !oldData.some(order2 => order1.name === order2.name && order1.slot === order2.slot);
});

</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```